# How does tailor (webfrontend for python fabric) work?

Tags: python, django, web-services, fabric

I am trying to setup tailor (I got fabric to work, pretty easy), but I have seriously NO idea how it works. The documentation of tailor ([here](http://tailor.readthedocs.org)) is cryptic at best. The quick start guide talks about a "client" and a "servent". Is this django terminology?

I assume the idea is that you have a tailor server which you can use with a tailor client, but why does the client part of the guide contain the stuff about the `fab` file, I would expect that to be in the server part.

Basically my question is: **What are the roles of the *client* and the *servent***?

If anyone can point me in the direction of additional documentation, or tell me about tailor first hand, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I agree the documentation is very confusing.  From looking at the code, the client has the following URL that is serving:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^api/v1/schema/$', schema, name='schema'),
)
```

So the schema function actually parses your fabfile and returns the fab commands that can be executed.

Now for the servent, the following URLs are defined:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^api/v1/fab/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', fab, name='fab'),
    url(r'^api/v1/projects/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', projects, name='project'),
    url(r'^api/v1/projects/$', projects, name='projects'),
)
```

The one that is fully implemented is the `fab` URL and that is the one that allows you to run a fab command. The `projects` URLs are not fully functional according to the code (It says buggy and doesn't have security), but I guess the idea is was to separate different projects of fab files.

Hope this helps.